# 74LS74 Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, flipflop, reset

I am a little new to digital logic circuits and found this circuit a little interesting. This is off a PCB that I desoldered and traced. It came out of a Molex terminal applicator. I was wondering what is going on with the flip-flop on the left. It lacks the PRE or D pins being connected to anything. It just has the CLK, CLR, and /Q pins being used. It's attached to a 34164 power monitor IC that sinks low when the 5V rail falls below 2.65V.

So, it looks like the CLK pin is low unless some presses a foot switch (N$13), which then pulses the CLK pin high. The CLR/Reset pin will likely be in a high state unless power falls below 2.65V (shouldn't happen hardly ever), or if the 4-Bit Binary Counter, U3, get's a Carry Over bit (once it counts up from 1 to 16, aka 4-bits).

I am guessing the flip flop is just being used as a "reset" switch for when power drops too low, or when the 4-bit binary counter goes over 4-bits?

[image: SN74LS74AN Circuit]

Comment: what's a "terminal applicator"?

Comment: That seems an adequate assessment of the circuit. Note that LS pins pull high when open; it's not good practice to rely on this, but it does work.

Comment: Terminal Applicator is a machine that automatically crimps terminals/pins/sockets to the ends of stripped wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U7 is a "reset supervisor" chip; it makes sure that the circuit powers up in a known state. In this case, it clears U1A, which drives the Q' output high, which in turn holds U3 in reset and disables U2A.

U6D is functioning as an inverter, so a falling edge on its input creates a rising edge on its output<sup>1</sup> that toggles U1A<sup>2</sup>. This allows U3 to count and enables U2A, which generates a series of pulses that operate the machine. When it gets to its final state, The CO' output of U3 goes low, which once again resets U1A.

So U1A is a simple 2-state FSM — "run" and "stop" — where a rising edge on its clock input puts it in the "run" state, and a low level on its clear input puts it in the "stop" state.

The machine won't run another cycle until another rising edge occurs, which requires the foot switch to be released and pressed again.

---

<sup>1</sup> It seems odd that there would be so many capacitors on the output of U6D — it's possible that you have traced this part of the circuit incorrectly. Those look like power supply decoupling capacitors.

<sup>2</sup> Note that this relies on the assumption that the open D input is interpreted as a "1" — as mentioned in the comments, it would be better to make that explicit in the design.

Comment: I thought that was odd too. The 220uF capacitor is the one silkscreened on the board. However, it looked like they added 0.1uF capacitors via bodge-wiring directly to pin 11 on the U6 NAND output and one on the CLK pin on the Flip-Flop. I am guessing maybe to stop a ringing on the line somewhere?

Comment: I doubt it. It would be very unusual for there to be ringing on a direct connection between two 74LS-family chips. If anything, the 220 uF capacitor would make the clock rise time very slow, **increasing** the likelihood that the circuit would malfunction.

Comment: On the FSM circuit, if I wanted to make that a CMOS component instead of a TTL one, on the unused Flip-Flop, I know to pull the PRE, D, and CLR to high and pull the CLK to low. On the "used" flip-flop, as I am not using the PRE or D pins, would I pull them to high as well?

Comment: Yes, pull them high.